# Request to be able to zoom in and out of pictures in Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04

Currently in Ubuntu there is no radio dial to be able to enlarge and reduce the size of pictures when viewed in the file manager or after being queued in the dash. Can this improvement be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ubuntu Brainstorm http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ . There you can submit any idea and track its progress as well.